# Cannot make WebSite work. How to assemble this code right?

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/GxuqQ/

If you click the above link, you will see an example of what I want to create. But right now I am trying to adopt this example. But it doesn't work.

I create a HTML document, a CSS document and a JavaScript document. I copy the code from the example to the right document. Everything should work. But it doesn't.

What am I doing wrong?

The bubble doesn't work. It just doesn't appear.

Comment: "Everything should work. But it doesn't." . You need to explain what isnt working in specific .

Comment: What exactly does not work? How do you know it's the "right document" and what does "right/correct" mean in that context? "It doesn't work." Is not question – thus the downvotes.

Comment: So you are showing us some code that works, which you have changed in some unspecified way, and you expect us to be able to tell why your unspecified change has broken it?

Answer (score 3):

Like I said you must put it below your HTML that contains id that you mention in JavaScript

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<style>
.pw-hint{
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    background-color:#EEE;
    color:black;
    max-width:300px;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding:5px;
    margin-top:22px;
}

.pw-hint:after {
    /*http://css-tricks.com/speech-bubble-arrows-that-inherit-parent-color/*/
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   top: -20px;
   left: 10px;
   border-bottom: 20px solid black;
   border-bottom-color: #EEE;
   border-left: 20px solid transparent;
   border-right: 20px solid transparent;
}

.pw-hint h2{
    font-size:20px;
    color:#D31515;
}
</style>    
</head>
<body>

<a href="#" id="link">click here</a>
<div class='pw-hint' id="hint"><h2>Warning!</h2> Lorem ipsum bla bla</div>
<script>
    document.getElementById("link").addEventListener("click", clicked);
      function clicked(){
       document.getElementById("hint").style.display = "block";
      }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```